# added ip-based virtual host to sites-available and created symlink to sites-enabled...but new domain times out

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I added ip-based virtual host to sites-availble and created symlink to sites-enabled, but new domain times out.

When i navigate to mynewdomain.com it says connection timed out.

```
NameVirtualHost 12.12.12.12
<VirtualHost 12.12.12.12>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName newdomain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/newdomain.com
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you add 12.12.12.12 to your server as a secondary address to one of its network interfaces? On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to add lines like the following to your **/etc/network/interfaces** file (making an assumption about the netmask):

```
auto eth0:12
iface eth0:12 inet static
 address 12.12.12.12
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 12.12.12.0
 broadcast 12.12.12.255
```

And then run `ifup eth0:12` as root.

Comment: And add the port at the end of the IP address in apache configuration like: `NameVirtualHost 12.12.12.12:80` and `<VirtualHost 12.12.12.12:80>`

Answer (score 0):

By `navigate to mynewdomain.com` I'm going to assume you actual mean `newdomain.com` which is what is mentioned in your example configuration.

**1:** That being said, make sure `newdomain.com` actually set in DNS to resolve to 12.12.12.12 and that the change has propagated through DNS.
**2:** Make sure to completely restart apache to make sure it picks up the new configuration. Do a `restart` or even better a `stop` then `start`.

Do you see any activity from your client's IP in the access log?